# Bigquery Updating Metadata but Disabled Create/Delete/Alter Tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-data-catalog

What roles should be properly assigned to a group/service account if we would like to be able to update table descriptions in a centralized dataset and other labels for Data Catalog?

We currently have this but this only allows the users to update tables that they have created. Not the centralized tables.

```
roles/datacatalog.tagEditor
roles/datacatalog.entryViewer
roles/datacatalog.tagTemplateCreator
roles/datacatalog.tagTemplateUser
```

I understand the role roles/bigquery.dataEditor will be able to cover this but we want users to only update existing table metadata but not allowed to delete or alter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to specifically update the metadata only you need to create a custom role. To do this you can follow the steps below:

- Open your Google Cloud console
- Select "IAM & Admin" -> Roles
- Click "+ Create Role"
- Edit "Title" to provide a descriptive role title. I used "Custom BigQuery metadata update"
- Click "+ Add Permissions"
- At the filter bar, put **bigquery.tables.update** and click "ADD"

  > - Permission **bigquery.tables.update** allows you to update the **TABLE METADATA ONLY**. See [permission list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bq-permissions) for reference.
  >   [image]
- Click "Create"

Once done, the created custom role that contains only **bigquery.tables.update** should be searchable when assigning roles in IAM.

[image]